# What is Conky, it's uses, and how is it implemented?

Tags: installation, conky

I'd like to know what Conky is. How to install it, any maintenance that's needed. Does it work with a specific Desktop Environment like Unity? Can it work with GNOME Classic? Details would be helpful. The more detailed and less confusing, the better. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Conky is a lightweight system monitor.  It sits wherever you put it in your desktop and tells you a bunch of system info like RAM usage, CPU, etc.  It can work in both Unity and GNOME Classic (not sure about GNOME3) and any Environment for that matter.

To install Conky, simply type `sudo apt-get install conky` in the terminal.  After the installation had completed, type `conky` in the terminal to launch it.

This is Conky with the [Conky-Lua theme](http://www.unixmen.com/configure-conky-lua-in-ubuntu-11-10-12-04-fedora-debian-and-linuxmint-howto-conky/).

[image]

To make Conky start immediately after you turn on your computer, search for "Startup Applications" in the Dash, then type`/usr/bin/conky` in the Command Area.  Type `Conky is Awesome` for the Description.